# Copying a database into a new database including structure and data

Tags: php, mysql

In phpMyAdmin under operations I can "Copy database to:" and select

- Structure and data
- CREATE DATABASE before copying
- Add AUTO_INCREMENT value

I need to be able to do that without using phpMyAdmin.

I know how to create the database and user.
I have a source database that's a shell that I can work from so all I really need is the how to copy all the table structure and data part.  (I know, the harder part)

**system**() & **exec**() are not options for me which rules out **mysqldump**. (I think)

How can I loop through each table and recreate it's structure and data?

Is it just looping through the results of

```
SHOW TABLES
```

then for each table looping through

```
DESCRIBE tablename
```

Then, is there an easy way for getting the data copied?

---

**UPDATE**:

So, I ended up going with:

```
SHOW TABLES;
```

for each table then I did

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE `tablename`;
```

and then

```
INSERT INTO `newBDname`.`tablename` SELECT * FROM `existingDBname`.`tablename`;
```

Comment: Can't you run `mysqldump` on the source database and plop that straight into a query in the SQL tab or via the import tool in phpMyAdmin?

Comment: I need to do this outside of phpMyAdmin and mysqldump is not currently an option.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use mysql_fetch_assoc on SHOW TABLES and then for each result, store the output of mysql_fetch_result SHOW CREATE TABLE $table_name and then issue mysql_query on $show_create_table

Hope that helps ... more into helping than doing it for you. :)

Comment: @Jason Actually, he posted 3 minutes after me. :P But all that matters is you got your solution!

Answer (score 3):

Use SELECT INTO to accomplish this.

```
SELECT * 
INTO destinationDB..newTable 
FROM sourceDB..existingTable
```

Comment: Can I do this across databases?

Comment: @Jason I've updated my example. That should work across databases.

Comment: Perfect...now if I could just accept your answer and @Spechal's together - they get me 100% of what I need.

Comment: That seemed to work at first then I got an Undeclared variable error but using INSERT INTO `db2`.`table2` SELECT * FROM `db1`.`table2`; worked